# "Aura Integration Service Error" When installing a private package

Tags: managed-package, appexchange, package, package-install

Our clients see this error when they try to install a new version of our package. I read [here](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000206360&language=en_US) and [here](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000206373&language=en_US) that this is because our package is not publicly listed on AppExchange. We don't want to list it yet but want to be able to install upgrades. As of now, no matter what we do, the installation link forwards to the (nonexistent) landingpage. How can this be resolved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Was the package just created? I get this error if I attempt to install a package immediately after its created. Waiting 5 minutes or so resolves the issue.

Comment: I also had the same error when trying to install in an expired trial org

Comment: Well, waiting 5 mores... or sometimes like 4 hours.